Sonar Qube Quality Gate is Failing in Android Webview
I have Enabled Javascript in my Android Webview but in sonar qube its showing Security vulnerability. but without javascript my webpage wont render. please help me to resolve this issue.
settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            settings.domStorageEnabled = true
            settings.allowContentAccess = false
            settings.allowFileAccess = false

